# Firebase functions.https.onCall returns null

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following firebase cloud function written in node.js that I call from my Android app.The function works fine but I get null when trying to get results in Android. I need return to my android app `console.log(result.data);` line, but that line called after firebase function completely done, so my Android app gets null.

*index.js*

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const subcheck = require('./subcheck');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.subcheck = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    subcheck.verifySubscription(data, context);
});
```

*And this is my subcheck.js*

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const key =  require('./service-account-key.json'); // JSON key file
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
    email: key.client_email,
    key: key.private_key,
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
});

const playDeveloperApiClient = google.androidpublisher({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: authClient
});

//admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.verifySubscription = function(data, context) {
    const skuId = data.sku_id;
    const purchaseToken = data.purchase_token;
    const packageName = data.package_name;

    return authClient.authorize()
        .then(function(result) {
            return playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.subscriptions.get({
                packageName: packageName,
                subscriptionId: skuId,
                token: purchaseToken
            }).then(function(result) {
                if (result.status === 200) {
                    console.log(result.data);
                    return {
                        data: result.data,
                        status: 200,
                        message: "Verified Subscription"
                    };
                } else {
                    console.log("Failed to verify subscription, Try again!");
                    return {
                        data: result.data,
                        status: 500,
                        message: "Failed to verify subscription, Try again!"
                    };
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

This is my firebase functions console log:

[image]

I'm trying to get results in Android with the following method :

```
    private Task<String> checkUserSubscribed(PurchaseHistoryRecord purchase) {
    Map<String, Object> mapUserPurchase = new HashMap<>();
    mapUserPurchase.put("sku_id", purchase.getSku());
    mapUserPurchase.put("purchase_token", purchase.getPurchaseToken());
    mapUserPurchase.put("package_name", "xxxxxxx");

    return mFirebaseFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("subcheck")
            .call(mapUserPurchase)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    return result;
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    String result = task.getResult();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "func results: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: It seems you return the same thing in case `result.status === 200` or not. Is it really your intention? Does `console.log(result.data); logs the correct value? Also, can you add the code used to call the Cloud Function from your app?

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste issue. console.log(result.data) logs correct value. I will add console log screenshots and my android call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably comes from the fact that you don't return the result of the call to the `verifySubscription()` function in:

```
exports.subcheck = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    subcheck.verifySubscription(data, context);
});
```

You should do:

```
exports.subcheck = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return subcheck.verifySubscription(data, context);
});
```

---

Also, you should probably re-organize your Promise chaining as follows, to avoid nesting the calls to `then()`, see more details/explanantions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

```
exports.verifySubscription = function(data, context) {
    const skuId = data.sku_id;
    const purchaseToken = data.purchase_token;
    const packageName = data.package_name;

    return authClient.authorize()
        .then(result => {
            return playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.subscriptions.get({
                packageName: packageName,
                subscriptionId: skuId,
                token: purchaseToken
            })
        })
        .then(result => {
                if (result.status === 200) {
                    console.log(result.data);
                    return {
                        data: result.data,
                        status: 200,
                        message: "Verified Subscription"
                    };
                } else {
                    console.log("Failed to verify subscription, Try again!");
                    return {
                        data: result.data,
                        status: 500,
                        message: "Failed to verify subscription, Try again!"
                    };
                }
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

---

Finally, you may have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) on error handling in a Callable Cloud Function. Instead of returning `{data: result.data,status: 500, ...};` you may throw an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`.